# TFS Build Template Copy Directory and Exclusion of files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have TFS Build Default Template and I added to it, between "Run on Agent' and "Check In Gated Changes for CheckInShelveset Builds", Copy Directory with Source BuildDetail.DropLocation and destination a shared directory on a server.

My problem comes that the Copy Directory is not executed or is executed, but no files are copied.

I am not sure if this is the right location to place this activity, but as I read the tutorial in msdn it seems correct. How can I force the built version of the web site be copied in a specific directory, and on a separate note is there a way to exclude some files from the copy? I wish to copy the built web site without copying the web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use copy activity which OOB and also if you use TFS 2013 default template it has post build activity which can run powershell